# How to sort list on the basis of count in django?

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a list of data and there is a total count field is one field which has total no of users I want to sort the data on the basis of the total count.

I tried to use  dictsort:"users_set.all.count" but didnt shows error.

```
 <tbody>

                                {% for item in data_list |dictsort:"users_set.all.count"%}
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>{% if item.users_set.all.count != 0 %}
                                            <a href="{% url 'cms:university-specific-display-of-student' %}?uni_id={{ item.id }}"
                                               id="{{ item.id }}">{{ item.name }}</a>{% else %}{{ item.name }}{% endif %}</td>
                                        <td class="text-center">{{ item.users_set.all.count }}</td>
                                        <td class="text-center"> {{ item.users_set.all|user_active_count:'2' }}</td>
                                        <td class="text-center">{{ item.users_set.all|user_active_count:'1' }}</td>
                                        <td class="text-center">{{ item.users_set.all|user_active_count:'3' }}</td>
                                    </tr>
                                {% endfor %}
                                </tbody>
```

Comment: I would suggest you to put sorting logic in your views not in template

Answer (score 0):

Maybe sort it in view using sorted and lambda. E.g.

```
a = sorted(a, key=lambda x: x.modified, reverse=True)
```

and then pass it to the template, so that the template code will be cleaner.